# can we make a programme where price increases everytime a purchase is done until we have no money left

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

this is the code

```
wallet = int(input("wallet = "))
price = 100
print("price = " + str(price))

while price <= 1000:
    if wallet >= price:
        ask = input('would you like to purchase again? (y/n)')
        if ask.upper() == "Y":
            left = int(wallet) - price
            wallet = left
            print("you now have " + str(left) + " left")
        elif ask.upper() == "N":
            print("transaction cancelled")
        else:
            print("invalid reply")
    left = wallet
    price += 100
    print('new price = ' + str(price))

else:
    print("you do not have enough money to purchase more")
    exit()
```

and this is the output

`wallet = 1000`

`price = 100`

`would you like to purchase again? (y/n)y`

`you now have 900 left`

`new price = 200`

`would you like to purchase again? (y/n)y`

`you now have 700 left`

`new price = 300`

`would you like to purchase again? (y/n)y`

`you now have 400 left`

`new price = 400`

`would you like to purchase again? (y/n)y`

`you now have 0 left`

`new price = 500`

`new price = 600`

`new price = 700`

`new price = 800`

`new price = 900`

`new price = 1000`

`new price = 1100`

`you do not have enough money to purchase more`

`Process finished with exit code 0`

i am making a continous purchase command where everytime a purchase is made, the price increase by 100, until no more money is left in customer's wallet. after which it should end but it first keeps incresing price for some time then stops.

Comment: Your loop keeps going until the price gets above 1000, even if you run out of money before that, because you define it like this: `while price <= 1000:`.  You should stop looping once you run out of money.  So maybe you want `while wallet > 0:`

Answer (score 0):

You should stop when you have not enough money

```
while wallet >= price:
```

---

Also here's a better code, with removed useless conversion to int/str, and useless `left` that is always equals to `wallet` when used

```
wallet = int(input("wallet = "))
price = 100
print("price =", price)

while and wallet >= price:
    ask = input('would you like to purchase again? (y/n)').upper()
    if ask == "Y":
        wallet -= price
        print("you now have", wallet, "left")
    elif ask == "N":
        print("transaction cancelled")
    else:
        print("invalid reply")
    price += 100
    print('new price =', price)
else:
    print("you do not have enough money to purchase more")
    exit()
```